# How to store protobuffer object in redis cache?

Tags: redis, protocol-buffers

I'm using Jedis as the java client to connect to Redis servers. I am also using protocol buffers to write the data in jedis or redis cache. But I'm not finding the way how to write or set the protobuf object to redis. Am I missing something or Jedis doesn't provide the way to store protobuf object as value?

Comment: Serialize it and store the bytes using [BinaryClient](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/BinaryClient.java).

Comment: You need to convert the protobuf data in a byte array and store it using the binary interface. Jedis supports String and byte array types. Other clients allow the use of Codecs where you are more in control of the Redis representation and mapping of the data.

Answer (score 16):

This is a late answer...

You can serialize the Protobuf message into a binary string, and save it to Redis using the `SET` command. However, whenever you need to get the Protobuf message, you have to get the binary string back, and deserialize it. Even if you only want to get a single field.

Another solution is that you can use the [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf) module to save the Protobuf message into Redis. With this module, you can read or write the Protobuf message. If you only need a single field, you don't need to get the whole message back, `redis-protobuf` will only return that field.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `redis-protobuf`.